# rewriting Map with forEach

Tags: javascript, loops, dictionary, asynchronous, foreach

The `forEach` method does not return a new string with the result of the values. 
If I want to rewrite the map method using `forEach`, I cannot use the command 
`push.forEach(array,callback)`.

I am attempting to use the `forEach` method to multiply each element in my array by 2 and store it in a new array. I do not want advice on using the `map` method because I know it already does this.

Without using the `forEach` method my code is as follows:

```
function MultiplyByTwo(num) {
    return num * 2;
}

function HostMultiplyByTwo(array,instructions) {
    var output = [];
    for (i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
        output.push(instructions(array[i]))
    }
    return output;
}

var endresult = HostMultiplyByTwo([1,2,3],MultiplyByTwo)
```

If the `forEach` function looks like this:

```
function forEach(array, callback) {
    for (var i =0;i<array.length;i++) {
        var result = callback(array[i])
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now I would like to be able to run `HostMutiplyByTwo` using the `forEach` method. Here is what I tried.

```
function HostMultiplyByTwo(array,instructions) {
    var output = [];
    forEach(array,instructions) {
        output.push(result)
    }
    return output;
}

var endresult = HostMultiplyByTwo([1,2,3],MultiplyByTwo)
```

This clearly does not work for some reason. I understand that the `forEach` method simply iterates through the first parameter and performs the function in its second parameter on the first parameter.

- Does it store the result of that operation somewhere afterwards?
- Is there a place where I can look to see the actual built-in function 'forEach' that my browser uses because I have not been able to find the precise definition in what it is doing?
- I cannot use push.forEach(array,instruction).
- Lets say I have an array named 'freeze'. Does it take 'freeze', perform an operation on each element in 'freeze' and then save the result of those operations back to 'freeze'?
- I am doing this because I would like practice using closures and callback functions. I understand that map returns an array after it performs a function on each element, but I do not understand how to do this using `forEach`.
- I have read online that you can use 'this.forEach' but I can't understand how the computer interprets the 'this'.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, you've already reimplemented `map` yourself. Your `HostMultiplyByTwo()` is actually a simple version of `map`. While it doesn't implement all the features of `map` as specified by the ECMAscript standard, it is similar to the `map` function in other languages.

Answer (score 4):

What do you think this is supposed to do?

```
forEach(array,instructions) {
    output.push(result)
}
```

`forEach` is just a method - it isn't a construct like `if`. If you use your function syntax (and not the built in method), You'll need to do something like

```
forEach(array, function (element) {
    output.push(instructions(element))
});
```

Notice the anonymous function wraps pushing the result of the function onto output - you get this for free from `map`.

You can avoid the anonymous function by using a named closure

```
var pusher = function (element) {
    output.push(instructions(element))
};

forEach(array, pusher);
```

You can even build the closure dynamically

```
var pusherCreator = function (outputArray, callback) {
    var pusher = function(element) {
        outputArray.push(callback(element));
    };

    return pusher;
};

forEach(array, pusherCreator(output, instructions));
```

Comment: Is there a way to make 'instructions' a function and not have to use 'function (element)' // because that is an anonymous function correct?

Comment: @JonathanMitchell It would need to be a closure. I'll add an example.

Answer (score -1):

Within the *forEach* function you have:

```
for (var i =0;i<array.length;i++) {
  var result = callback(array[i])
}
```

which just assigns a new value to *result* on each iteration. You need to assign the value to an array, so:

```
var result = [];
for (var i =0;i<array.length;i++) {
  result.push(callback(array[i]));
}
```

Now in the *HostMultiplyByTwo* function, you just need:

```
var output = forEach(array,instructions)
return output;
```

or just:

```
return forEach(array,instructions);
```

Note that by convention, variable names starting with a capital letter are reserved for constructors. Variables with all capitals are for constants.

So the whole thing looks like:

```js
function multiplyByTwo(num) {
    return num * 2;
}

function forEach(array, callback) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    result.push(callback(array[i]));
  }
  return result;
}

function hostMultiplyByTwo(array,instructions) {
    return forEach(array,instructions)
}

document.write(hostMultiplyByTwo([1,2,3], multiplyByTwo));
```

Note that if you want to deal with sparse arrays and properly replicate *map* and *forEach* (which only visit members that exist), you need to test if each *i* member of the source array exists, so *forEach* becomes:

```
  for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    if (array.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      result[i] = callback(array[i]);
    }
  }
```

So that non–existent members remain non–existent.

Comment: No, He does not need to create an array, and push onto it, in `forEach`. You are right that he does not need to assign the result of the computation, or return it, but that is harmless. Essentially you are suggesting turning `forEach` into `map`, which is not the point.

Comment: @torazaburo—"*I am attempting to use the forEach method to multiply each element in my array by 2 and store it **in a new array**.*" so yes, the OP must create a new array. If that doesn't happen in the *forEach* function then it must happen in the *HostMultiplyByTwo* function and *forEach* must return something, and that something must be another array since functions can only return one value.

Comment: @torazaburo—oh, and the subject is "*rewriting Map with forEach*" which indicates that a kind of *map* replacement is required.

Comment: which is exactly what the routine he calls `HostMultiplyByTwo` is.

Comment: @torazaburo—in that case, *HostMultiplyByTwo* must pass the result array to *forEach* to modify, something like `forEach(source, fn, target)` and if *target* is undefined, it operates on *source* directly, otherwise it puts the results in *target*. That's the only alternative I see working as a new array must be created some time and *forEach* must assign the values.